# Css for mobile android devices: white border above background-image doesn't want to dissapear

Tags: android, css, mobile

I have a problem with my css on mobile dives with an android system.
I can't remove the white space above my background-image.

Here is my css code:

```
.mobile #main2{
padding:0px;
margin:0px auto;

}

.mobile #main2 .big_bg2{
padding:0px;
margin:0px auto;
top:0;
z-index:-1;

}



.mobile + #main2 .big_bg2 img{
    padding:0 !important;
    margin-left:-35px !important;
    margin-top:10px !important;




}

.mobile + #main2 .big_bg2 > a,  .big_bg2 > a > img{
    float:none !important;
}
```

Comment: suggesting avoid usage `!important` in CSS code

Comment: any reason to avoid !important ??

Comment: I have this problem only on a android device phone, not a iphone. Whet is the big difference? I have also a seperate css code for the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the body has the default bowser's padding and/or margin, try

```
body{margin:0; padding:0}
```